# In Erlang SASL Crash Report, what exactly is the meaning of the "messages:" field?

Tags: erlang, error-logging, sasl

Is the messages field in a sasl crash report the current content of the messages mailbox i.e. the unrecieved messages?

Or is it the messages history, the last received messages?

If it shows the received messages in what order are they shown?

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 8-May-2011::09:00:38 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: most_msgs:-connect/4-fun-0-/0
    pid: <0.181.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {tx_succ_timeout,mcm}
      in function  most_msgs:wait_tx_succ/4
    ancestors: [<0.178.0>,<0.177.0>,<0.175.0>,<0.174.0>,<0.173.0>,<0.172.0>]
    messages: [{send,{most_mcm,{most_fdh,mcm,undefined,undefined,968,6,255},
                                  80,set,undefined,undefined,
                                  <<244,239,62,2>>}},
                  {recv,{most_icm,768,status,<<2>>}},
                  {recv,{most_fifo_status,mcm,0,net_off,1}},
                  {send,{most_mcm,{most_fdh,mcm,undefined,undefined,968,6,255},
                                  80,set,undefined,undefined,
                                  <<244,223,62,128>>}},
```

Comment: use this "erlang:process_info(list_to_pid(PID),message_queue_len)." at run time to check if the mail box is getting overloaded with unreceived messages.. I think they were the contents in the mailbox before crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-2

{messages, MessageQueue}

MessageQueue is a list of the messages to the process, which have not yet been processed.

---

Most of the information comes from process_info (lib/stdlib/src/proc_lib.erl). Not sure about the order of messages though.

Answer (score 0):

it is the messages in the message queue at the time when the process crashed.

Comment: Any reference? I have the hunch too but didn't find documented how it really is.

Comment: Only experience and logic as it cannot really be anything else. There would be a severe memory strain if processed messages were kept for all processes.